# GKMatchmakerViewController delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, sdk, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I spent hours trying to debug this one so I thought I'd post here to help perhaps save someone the headache!

```
GKMatchRequest *matchRequest = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
matchRequest.minPlayers = 2;
matchRequest.maxPlayers = 2;
GKMatchmakerViewController *controller = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:matchRequest];
controller.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was that I was missing the fact that the controller delegate is not the correct delegate to set!  Use matchmakerDelegate and all will be well!

```
controller.matchmakerDelegate = self;
```